# In Excel, return all values from separate sheet for columns with matching headers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I need to pull all values from columns with matching data headers from a sheet we'll call "Source" to a sheet we'll call "Destination", under the matching header.

For instance, there is a column with header "Address" in both sheets. In the Source sheet, that column contains URLs. I need a way to pull all of these URLs into the "Address" column in the Destination sheet.

I'm not sure if this will make a difference, but I need to do the same for quite a few columns in these sheets.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, there is a way. See [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65). Also available in [Our 10 most popular functions](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Excel-functions-by-category-5f91f4e9-7b42-46d2-9bd1-63f26a86c0eb).

Comment: @Jeeped Wouldn't it be HLOOKUP if I'm looking for a column header value to return results for all items in that column? Also, how would one go about grabbing all values under that column, rather than a single cell value? Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you could use [HLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-f3f3b210-5dd6-4b58-9c83-b9db2c306d6a) with `ROW(1:1)` supplying hte row. An [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair would do as well. It is hard to recommend anything based on what little I know about the worksheet design.

Answer (score 0):

You could paste this formula in every cell on the Destination sheet that you want to pull a value for. You will need to change the forumla from $A:$Z and from $A$1:$Z$1 to something else depending on how many columns are in the source sheet:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(Source!$A:$Z,ROW(),MATCH(A$1,Source!$A$1:$Z$1,0))),"",INDEX(Source!$A:$Z,ROW(),MATCH(A$1,Source!$A$1:$Z$1,0)))
```